# What is "Field Summary" in API?

Tags: java, field, javadoc

OK so I am new to this fourm and this is my first question. So I have been given an API and the first thing I see is the Field Summary which I dont understand.

Field Summary:

```
  static int - DEFAULT_FIRST //the First digit of the default code
  static int - DEFAULT_SECOND //the second digit of the default code
```

That is what it says on the API and I have no idea what that means. Can someone help me with figuring this one out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143461/field-summary-on-java-api-doc

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html "field" = class / instance variables. They are in your case the values used by default and made public constants so you can use them in your code.